# Java HashMap generics with Class key

Tags: java, generics

How do I stop the compiler from complaining at map.get()?

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from ClassInfo<capture#1-of ?> to ClassInfo<T>"

```
class Context
{
    final private Map<Class<?>,ClassInfo<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    <T> ClassInfo<T> getClassInfo(Class<T> c)
    {
        ClassInfo<T> ci = map.get(c);
        if (ci == null) {
            ci = new ClassInfo<T>(c);
            map.put(c, ci);
        }
        return(ci);
    }
}
```

Some more information:

ClassInfo contains data about Class, gathered via reflection.

The compiler error does NOT occur with the JDK javac, only when using the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: what do you think this line is supposed to do? `<T> ClassInfo<T> getClassInfo(Class<T> c)`

Comment: You can enclose Context<T> and declare the Map with T

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem adding a ()cast to the code:

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

```
class Context
{
    private final Map<Class<?>,ClassInfo<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>,ClassInfo<?>>();

    <T> ClassInfo<T> getClassInfo(Class<T> c)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ClassInfo<T> ci = (ClassInfo<T>) map.get(c);
        if (ci == null) {
            ci = new ClassInfo<T>(c);
            map.put(c, ci);
        }
        return(ci);
    }
}
```

Be aware though, casts are usually dangerous, and you should only use them if you are really sure that object is in fact what you are expecting.

The downside of this solution is that it will create a warning, which I had to suppress. Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't really work. Now there is a compiler error and a compiler warning. The error reads: Type safety: Unchecked cast from ... to .... And the warning reads: Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"). It could be that my eclipse compiler settings are a little bit too restricted.

Comment: I enabled the following compiler option of Eclipse: "Suppress optional errors with '@SuppressWarnings'". Now the code is without errors or warnings. But when executing this method, I get an Error exception "Unresolved compilation problem".

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it and use :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ClassInfo<T> ci = (ClassInfo<T>) map.get(c);
```

Make sure that you are putting Type T into the hash map other wise casting exception can happen.

That is if T represents String, then map.get(c) should always return either null or ClassInfo

Comment: The compiler error changed from "Type mismatch" to "Type safety"... (see first answer)

Comment: that is just a warning.. to clear that warning, check my updated answer